# How do I convince my patient that he's actually dead?

Tags: two-point-hospital

I've got a patient I don't know how to deal with.  You see...he's dead.  But I can't tell *him* that; he's stuck trying to go to the bathroom.  His case of deadness struck just as he was entering the stall, and now all he does is stand there.  Blocking the door to the toilet stall. People go around him and use it, and don't seem to care that he's there.  But I do!  He's in front of the line for my Injection Room, and I can't convince anyone to just ignore him and keep going.

I deleted the Toilets he's in.  He just stands there.  I closed the Injection Room he's queued for.  He just stands there.  And is first in line when I open it back up.  I don't really care if he actually dies; I just want him to stop clogging up hospital services!

What can I do to convince this zombie that he doesn't need treatment anymore?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, this bug has been brought up to the developer, who acknowledged it was a bug and offered no help in actually fixing it. Other people have the same issue but nobody I've found has actually found a way around it. Hotfixes that have been released since the bug was reported don't explicitly report any fixes either.

I think your zombie patient is stuck there until the celestial powers-that-be come up with a workaround.

https://steamcommunity.com/app/535930/discussions/1/1737715419901973932/

Comment: Assuming they'll actually look at the save, asking players to send their affected saves seems like a start to me... can't fix a bug you have no idea how to reproduce consistently.

Answer (score 3):

While I haven't found a way for the patient to acknowledge their own mortality, you can resolve the services aspect by deleting the room they're holding up, and rebuilding it.

The zombie is still standing there, and I've found a few friends for him.  But for the moment, none of them want treatment, and they just kinda stand there.